# Cookies not being saved to correct location Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, cookies

In Asp.Net 4.0 I am writing a cookie using the HttpCookie Class. Debugging with IE9. The cookie is being saved to "/". Shouldn't it be saving to [user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files? When I try to find it there it does not exist. And how can I change this?

```
 Dim cookie_name As String = "ProjectId"
 Dim cookie As New HttpCookie(cookie_name)
 cookie.Value = "123456789"
 cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8)
 Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)

 Debug.Print(cookie.Path.ToString) 'cookie is saving to "/"
```

Comment: cookie.path defines the base domain *URLs* the cookie applies to, its got nothing to do with the client file-system (which you don't need to worry about)

Comment: So if it is not in [Temporary Internet Files] where would it be? I did a search for the cookie name on the entire system and did not find it.

Comment: Roaming? http://www.milincorporated.com/a2_cookies.html

Comment: @AlexK. You are correct. I did not have [Hide protected operating system files] unchecked. Thanks for the link. If you write answer then i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cookie.path` defines the base domain URLs the cookie applies to, its got nothing to do with the client file-system (which you don't need to worry about).

[This](http://milincorporated.com/a2_cookies.html) describes how to find the cookie's physical path.

Answer (score 0):

Alex K is quite correct, here's the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) for the Cookie.Path property which states:

> The Path property specifies the subset of URIs on the origin server to
>   which this Cookie applies. If this propery is not specified, then this
>   Cookie will be sent to all pages on the origin server or servers.

Comment: At first the application was writing the cookie to [Temporary Internet Files] then it stopped writing to this area and I cannot locate the cookie anywhere.